# Can Blindsight see through walls?

Tags: dnd-5e, player-characters

The reason I'm asking this (when it's been asked before) is because I'm playing an Animated Armor, which technically HAS no senses. It's just magic in a shell. (Ghost in the shell, anyone?) So that begs the question, does something that's purely magical have the ability to see through walls? And if so, can it be stopped by that so many feet of wood, stone, iron, and lead? My question is stemmed off of the homebrew race (and the monster) https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Animated_Armor_(5e_Race)

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. To be clear, is this a character you are playing or a concept you are thinking of? By default players can't just play as monsters like animated armour, hence why HeyICanChan asked if you had a link to the rules you are using. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Ohh.. just a homebrew race. https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Animated_Armor_(5e_Race)

Comment: @WillemRenzema: If relevant, those should be addressed/resolved in an answer to the question, rather than a comment on the question. (The first linked tweet is brought up in comments on several answers to the question this is marked as a duplicate of, but none of the answers address either one.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Assuming you are talking about 5e-dnd:

> A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight, within a specific radius. Creatures without eyes, such as oozes, and creatures with echolocation or heightened senses, such as bats and true dragons, have this sense.

The rule doesn't say what blocks blindsight generally, but I would rule it based on the type of sense. Vibration-based senses like oozes may be able to sense through walls and floors, while bats probably cannot sense behind solid walls. Scent-based blindsight may depend on the type of obstruction, with walls more blocking than bushes.

It's up to the DM to decide for the specific creature and environment.

Comment: But It's animated Armor, it doesn't quite fit in with those things...

Comment: What's it supposed to sense?

Comment: I'm attempting logic here, as the creation of Animated Armor is a (relatively) simple process that takes multiple steps, but you don't give it eyes, ever... How's it see?

Comment: The DM can decide how the sense of animated armor works in detail.

Comment: Fair enough... Welp, time to bend the rules until he says how it sees directly... Heheh. Wonder how long that'll last